# How can I save an audio recording on app crash?

Tags: android, ios, audio, ionic-framework, plugins

I'm trying to build a custom Android plugin for an Ionic app. This plugin is used to record audio. When the app crashes or is killed by the user my `FileOutputStrem` is not closed correctly and my `MediaPlayer` no longer plays the file (which has the correct filepath). I am looking for a solution that is a sort of autosave function. So I want to save the recording every x seconds during the recording. Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Recording is done like this:

```
final byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    isRecording = recording;

    try {
        os = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (os != null) {
        while (isRecording) {
            int read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                try {
                    os.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If more info is needed please let me know

PS. I also need a solution for iOS :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the `os.close` in the finally block?

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem is that it might never reach that part because of a crash of app kill by the user